# How to list categories in reverse alphabetical order?

Tags: categories

I am organising posts on a blog-type website into "issues", each containing 10 articles and assigned a unique category such as `issue7`.

Using a sidebar widget I want to list these categories so that a user can click on "Issue 7" and they will bring up all the articles in category `issue7`, namely articles 61-70.

It's straightforward to list them in alphabetical order of the category names. But how can I list them in reverse alphabetical order of those names, such that the link "Issue 3" (for category `issue3`) appears before "Issue 2" and the link to the latest "issue" appears at the top?

I'm using Astra with a child theme. I've tried putting the following into `functions.php` in the child theme, but to no effect:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
'orderby'    => 'name',
'order'      => 'DESC',
'hide_empty' => 0
) );
```

(I realise that once I go over Issue 9 I will probably have to rename category `issue1` as `issue01`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine arguments for 'category' taxonomy ONLY:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'my_term_args', 10, 2 );

function my_term_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    // don't affect admin area passing back default arguments
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $args;
    }

    // check the taxonomy in use and redefine it's default arguments
    if( in_array( 'category', $taxonomies ) ) {
        $args['orderby']    = 'name';
        $args['order']      = 'DESC';
        $args['hide_empty'] = false;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Also, `get_terms()` syntax you've posted is obsolete since version 4.5. The new syntax look like this:

```
<?php
$categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category'
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, which works great. But are you saying it would also be possible to use `get_terms()` with the new syntax?

Comment: Yes, but only if you develop your own widget.